# How to automatically delete delete/recreate custom branches in Github after merge?

Tags: github

I have three branches in my repo:

`master` -- (1)

`pipeline/delete` -- (2)

`pipeline/dr`-- (3)

After I merge from my fork to `master` -> I want to automatically delete and recreate (2) and (3). This should happen on each merge. I've seen the Github feature in settings that automatically deletes HEAD but thats not what I want here. Could someone suggest how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can with enabling the setting seen below. The setting is in the `General` section of the settings tab.

[image]

Comment: but this wont recreate those custom branches

Comment: Also master is my default branch (HEAD?) I dont want to delete master. Just the (2) and (3)